# Ignoring variable in Python multiline string

Tags: python

I'm forwarding an HTML e-mail using a Python script, which is in a multi line string. It needs to read 4 externally given variables (which work). But there's a mail:to link which uses %20 and %40. I'm using %s to refer to the other objects. When I try to execute the script, it gives the following error:

> TypeError: %o format: a number is required, not str

Which I understand, as it expects the %20 and %40 to be a reference to a variable too. I really want to include the mail:to link, but I can't seem to make Python ignore the values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list1=[0,1,2,3,4];

import mimetypes, os, smtplib, sys, 
from email import encoders
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email.utils import make_msgid


me = "xx@yy.nl"
you = "yy@xx.nl"
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]
PASS='password'
SRVSMTP='mysmtpserv:587'
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
msg['Date'] = formatdate()
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()

sys.argv[3].split(";")
hostnam, trgname, trgstat, trgseve = sys.argv[3].split(";")
print sys.argv[3].split(";")

text = """ plaintext email here
"""
html = """
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="margin-left: 80px;"><strong>Trigger:</strong> %s trgname <br />
<strong>Status</strong>: %s  trgstat <br />
<strong>Severity:</strong> %s  trgseve </p>

<p style="margin-left: 40px;"><a href="mailto:xx%40yy.nl?bcc=yy%40xx.com&amp;body=insert%20text%2C%0A%0Ahere%20for%20the%20emailA%5BFirmname%5D%0A%5B%28Address%29%20Adressline2%5D">Click here</a> &nbsp;<strong> %s hostnam.</strong><br />
&nbsp;</p>
<a href="mailto:xxxyyy@yxy.com?subject=Unsubscribe%20me">Click here to unsubscribe</a>&nbsp;</span><br />
&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
""" % ('hostnam', 'trgname', 'trgstat', 'trgseve', 'hostnam')

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(SRVSMTP)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(me, PASS)
smtpserver.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.quit()
```

Comment: you can go with [pilu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814497/6663095). It's recommended and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `format` call instead of the `%` you are currently using.

In your example, replace all the `%s` by `{}` and then replace `% ('hostnam', 'trgname', 'trgstat', 'trgseve', 'hostnam')` by `.format(hostnam, trgname, trgstat, trgseve, hostnam)`

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to be working. It won't present the values correctly, it will present them as the plain text 'hostnam', 'trgname' etc.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that, with this method and the template strings, the OP could also remove the duplicate reference to hostnam by using positional or named replacement fields

Comment: @Melanchole So does your code example ;) Remove the single quotes around the variable names

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry I didn't see your comments earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

How about [template strings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#template-strings)?

```
from string import Template

print(Template("here be %20 %40 my ${placeholder}string").safe_substitute(placeholder="amazing"))

# here be %20 %40 my amazing string
```

Available since Python 2.4

Comment: Huh, there's a _third_ way to do string interpolation in Python? I never knew... I guess this predates `str.format`.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the unwanted `%` characters by doubling them:

```
<p style="margin-left: 40px;"><a href="mailto:xx%%40yy.nl?bcc=yy%%40xx.com&amp;body=insert%%20text%%2C%%0A%%0Ahere%%20for%%20the%%20emailA%%5BFirmname%%5D%%0A%%5B%%28Address%%29%%20Adressline2%%5D">Click here</a> &nbsp;<strong> %s hostnam.</strong><br />
```

It's a bit tedious and the other answers are probably better; I'm just mentioning this for completeness.